# How to set up xcode schemes for an Android Studio Flutter project

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have a Flutter project in Android Studio which uses Flutter Flavors.  I understand that the Xcode "equivalent" is to use schemes and found various blogs and how-tos explaining this but they all seem to assume that I can open the project in Xcode.

Is there a way to open the project in Xcode?  Can I do that and then still work in Android Studio (to build/debug the Flutter/dart code)

Can I create the Xcode schemes inside the Android Studio project?

Is there some other solution?

Note: running `xcodebuild -list` inside the AndroidStudio project directory says "error The directory does not contain an Xcode project, workspace or package` which makes me hopeful of being able to just fix that and then be able to create the schemes, and then go back to using flutter via Android Studio.

I asked [How do you use Flutter Flavors in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145608/how-do-you-use-flutter-flavors-in-xcode) but this question seems to be the first step in answering all those questions.

Comment: I have discovered the command `open ios/Runner.xcworkspace`, which is executed from the Flutter project directory.